# Remove even numbered lines of text file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a text file on a Linux system, and would like to remove every second line, which is "even" numbered. Example: I would like to remove the second line of the file, the fourth, sixth, eighth line, and so on, until you complete filtering of the file completely.

### file.txt

```
86850343
88065952
89381968
89536251
89714939
89826424
90124775
90672109
91408453
92438737
```

I would like this output:

```
86850343
89381968
89714939
90124775
91408453
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU Sed's `n-skip-m` notation:

```
$ sed '2~2d' file.txt
86850343
89381968
89714939
90124775
91408453
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't really beat `sed` for this sort of thing, but here are some other options:

```
$ awk 'NR%2!=0' file
86850343
89381968
89714939
90124775
91408453

$ perl -ne '$.%2 && print' file
86850343
89381968
89714939
90124775
91408453

$ perl -ne 'print if $.%2' file
86850343
89381968
89714939
90124775
91408453

$ perl -ne 'not $.%2 && print' file
86850343
89381968
89714939
90124775
91408453
```

Comment: Heh, the first 3 of those give incorrect output based on the question; the fourth gives the right result :-)

Comment: @StephenHarris eeeek! Completely fumbled that one. Thanks for the heads up, fixed now.